# Change text block foreground

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have  RGB color like this `#dc020d` 
 and I have a text block and I want to make the foreground of the text block equal to the RGB color that I have as a string.

I tried

```
var bc = new BrushConverter();

tb.Foreground = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FFXXXXXX");
```

but it didn't work, although I'm using `System.Windows.Media`.

The only way I found `Color.FromArgb()` but it takes four bytes, I couldn't convert the string to four bytes.

Comment: get the RBG of the hexa value using http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/hex-to-rgb/color-converter.php

Comment: see the sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromargb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ray i want to do this in c#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a method taking a string of hex colour and returning a `SolidColorBrush`.

Like:

```
public SolidColorBrush GetBrushFromHexColor(string hexColor)
{
    return new SolidColorBrush(
        Color.FromArgb(
            Convert.ToByte(hexColor.Substring(1, 2), 16),
            Convert.ToByte(hexColor.Substring(3, 2), 16),
            Convert.ToByte(hexColor.Substring(5, 2), 16),
            Convert.ToByte(hexColor.Substring(7, 2), 16)
        )
    );
}
```

And call this function into the line where you set your colour to text block.

```
MyTxt.Foreground = GetBrushFromHexColor("#ffdc020d");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
// the same with #94b301
Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0x94, 0xb3, 0x01);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

```
// Description : Extension methods for using applying solid color in WinRT XAML projects.
// Owner : Farhan Ghumra
// Contact : https://www.facebook.com/farhan.ghumra
//           https://twitter.com/_F4RH4N_
// Example :
// MyRectagle.Fill = ColorExtensions.FromName("SkyBlue");
// MyTextBlock.Foreground = ColorExtensions.FromHex("#379988");

using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using System.Reflection;

namespace App1
{
    public static class ColorExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// It gives solid color brush from hexadecimal color code.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="HexColor">Color code in hexadecimal format (Example : #123456 or #12345678)</param>
        /// <returns>New instance of SolidColorBrush accoiding to hexadecimal color.</returns>
        public static SolidColorBrush FromHex(string HexColor)
        {
            byte A, R, G, B;

            if (HexColor.Length == 7)
            {
                A = 255;
                R = HexColor.Substring(1, 2).ToByte();
                G = HexColor.Substring(3, 2).ToByte();
                B = HexColor.Substring(5, 2).ToByte();
                return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B));
            }

            else if (HexColor.Length == 9)
            {
                A = HexColor.Substring(1, 2).ToByte();
                R = HexColor.Substring(3, 2).ToByte();
                G = HexColor.Substring(5, 2).ToByte();
                B = HexColor.Substring(7, 2).ToByte();
                return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B));
            }

            else
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// It gives solid color brush from color name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">Color name as string.</param>
        /// <returns>New instance of SolidColorBrush according to color name.</returns>
        public static SolidColorBrush FromName(string ColorName)
        {
            var ColorProperty = typeof(Colors).GetRuntimeProperty(ColorName);

            if (ColorProperty != null)
                return new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorProperty.GetValue(null));
            else
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts hexadecimal color code channel (Alpha, Red, Blue, Green) to byte type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ColorCodePart">Hexadecimal color code channel (Alpha, Red, Blue, Green)</param>
        /// <returns>byte value parsed from Hexadecimal color code channel</returns>
        private static byte ToByte(this string ColorCodePart)
        {
            return byte.Parse(ColorCodePart, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        }
    }
}
```